# In XSLT, how do I get a character's hex code as literal text?

Tags: xslt, character-encoding

I'm finding all sorts of conversions, but I'm trying to get the actual string of characters that make up a found character's hex string.  So, if the XSLT

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="Message" regex="([&#x1f1;-&#x1f699;])">
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="emjtxt"/>...
```

Encountered the XML

```
<Message>Very funny! </Message>
```

Later in the XSLT, I want the result of

```
<xsl:value-of select="$emjtxt"/>
```

...to give the actual text '&#x16F60B' and not the character ''

I'd tried codepoint-to-string, but that didn't help.  There must be some function that I'm just not finding, because I'm not sure exactly how to pose the question without getting all of these conversion suggestions.

Oh, and I'm using XSLT 2, and Saxon HE 9.4.0.4

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What counts as a useful solution here seems likely to depend on why you want the hex representation of the character.

**If you just want the output to have numeric character references** instead of literals for characters outside the range U+0020 to U+007F, the simplest approach is to specify an xsl:output encoding value that names a character set that does not include the characters in question.  When those characters are output, they will be output as numeric character references (you probably won't have control over whether they are decimal or hex).

**If it were a single particular character,** or a small number of characters, you were interested in, the simplest solution would be a character map.  From your sample code, I don't guess that's the case.

**If you want to perform some special processing on the hex value,** though, you want a function which takes a character as input and returns the hexadecimal numeral representing the input character's UCS code point.  As far as I know, there is no built-in function that does this; nor (unless I have overlooked it repeatedly) is there a built-in that takes an integer and a base and returns a string representing that integer in that base.  So the challenge is to write one.

The simplest solution decomposes the problem into two parts:  first, write a function which accepts an integer and returns a hexadecimal representation of that integer.  Here is a simple implementation of such a function (not tested):

```
<xsl:function name="my:i2x" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="i" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$i lt 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('-', my:i2x(-1 * $i))"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$i eq 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="quot" select="$i idiv 16"/>
      <xsl:variable name="rmdr" select="$i mod 16"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(
          my:i2x($quot),
          substring('0123456789ABCDEF', $rmdr + 1, 1)
        )"
      />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

It's now easy to write a wrapper function to accept a character and call local:i2x() on that character's code point:

```
<xsl:function name="my:c2x" as="xs:string ">
  <xsl:param name="s" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($s) != 1">
      <xsl:message terminate="yes">
        The argument to local:c2x should be a single character, 
        not a longer or shorter string.
      </xsl:message>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="my:i2x(string-to-codepoints($s))"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

If you want, you can make c2x() return a numeric character reference (but be careful when you try to serialize it, lest you get `&amp;#x01F60B;` instead of `&#x01F60B;`.  (And as noted above -- if what you want is just to get numeric character references in the output instead of literals, this is not the approach to take.)